# Hillshading for small, flat areas in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, hillshade

I have a grid of approximately 172 points with elevation heights for one mound on a flat land. The surface of the mound is 200x200 meters, and the height towards the center is 3 meters.

I did TIN interpolation and created a DEM file which looks excellent. But, when I try to apply hillshade, I get mostly noticeable quadrants which is understandable because of the small surface and the not so big density of the points.

How can I improve the hillshade of my DEM? I experimented with the z-factor, azimuth etc, but still no luck.

Comment: Can we see what the hillshade looks like? How did you hillshade? Are the 172 points gridded or do they follow breaklines?

Comment: Are the elevation values rounded to full meters? This will obviously look strange when applying a hillshade.